# Кто вызвал Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

правлю чужой проект на NodeJS

ошибка вылетает в Promise

текст ошибки не информативен:

> ReferenceError: num is not defined

console.trace остановился на timers.js

как еще можно узнать кто вызвал Promise?

**добавил**

trace ошибки:

```
Trace: [ReferenceError: room is not defined]
at callback2 (/var/www/html/kurento/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/promisecallback/index.js:39:17)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (/var/www/html/kurento/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:331:16)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (/var/www/html/kurento/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:343:17)
at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (/var/www/html/kurento/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:314:11)
at Object.lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/var/www/html/kurento/node_modules/kurento-client/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js:125:9)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Comment: ошибка ссылается на строку в файле?

Comment: надо смотреть кто пытается использовать переменную num до того как она определена, хотя скорее всего она просто не в области видимости

Comment: @Grundy, по trace видны несколько вызовов в  `/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js` и в финале `timers.js:300:15`

Comment: @vnn198, к сожалению `num` используется по всему проекту и в разных интерпретациях, хотел пойти от обратного, от `exception`

Comment: можешь добавить полный текст ошибки и стектрейса?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил текст ошибки

Comment: _room_ или _num_?

Comment: кроме этой ошибки до/после нее еще ошибки выводятся?

Comment: @Grundy, на серваке нет, но после нее в клиенте возникает ошибка: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: STATE_INPROGRESS`

Comment: @Grundy, room, num привел для абстракции

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45971/discussion-between-grundy-and-ravend).